# Dynamic Content for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web-hosting, dynamic-content

I am currently starting work on an iOS App which will display new content weekly. The app will need to display videos and text as well as a few images.

The problem is that I need to be able to update the content the app shows without releasing a new update every time. Therefore I am at a loss as to how to display all of these different elements 'remotely'.

For the videos I was thinking that I may be able to simply host the weeks video on a web server and then create a link to that to display it in the app with the iOS media player. Either way I think that text could be a problem. Please could you suggest on some relatively simple ways to go about doing something like this?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,
Dylan

PS Would it be worth doing something like this native as opposed to packaging an HTML5 document as an app with Cocoon JS? (as all the content would be pulled in from the web anyway)

Comment: Serve it off the web. Look at the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) class.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Obviously the simple thing to do is just to set up a responsive website on something like Wordpress for easy CMS but wan't the app to feel native and have the ability to add in ads.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from 3rd-party platforms (which have their own pros and cons), you should at least investigate how you would programmatically do this (because in some cases, you'll still have to do some of the work yourself).

Look into "background fetch", silent remote notifications, and NSURLSession background downloads. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

As to native/HTML5/hybrid, that's a philosophical landmine that has no "right" answer. Look to the experience of what you want to do *with* the content as to how appropriate the different approaches might be (performance, features, impact of offline storage, etc).

Comment: Ok will look in to the background fetch stuff. At the moment, looking at different CMS solutions such as Parse which was mentioned below.

Comment: How you manage the content does overlap and interact with how you retrieve the data (as well as how you present the data), but they are not _necessarily_ the same things. As you educate yourself on the alternatives, the different use cases should start becoming apparent.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! will report back if I have any other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

well i would recommend that you try parse , you can build a very simple cms to your app and integrate easily with your native component , its free and have excellent tutorial , learning curve from zero to hero is few hours

https://parse.com

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check it out now!